# Conditional parenthesized substring matches with replace

Tags: javascript, regex

Working on a regex phone number formatting solution and I'd like to include the potential for users entering an extension.

For example if the user enters something similar to `+121255512341212`, their input is formatted to `+1 (212) 555-1234 ext 1212` via the following

However if the user enters a number without an extension (e.g. `+12125551234`), the output still includes the `ext`

```
var reg = /(\+?\d{1})?\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})?\W*\s*(\d+)?/g; 
var substr = '$1 ($2) $3-$4 ext $5'; 

'+121255512341212'.replace(reg, substr); // '+1 (212) 555-1234 ext 1212'
'+12125551234'.replace(reg, substr); // '+1 (212) 555-1234 ext'
```

Existing issues in the above code snippet aside....Is there a way I can build a conditional into `substr` so that `ext` is only output when `$5` has actual content?

Or am I going about this the wrong way...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One additional replacement does the trick:

```
.replace(reg, substr).replace(/ ext $/, "");
```